# scanf_s не читает ввод при повторном вызове

Tags: c++

```
char s[11];
if (scanf_s("%[a-z]s", s, 10)) printf("String1: %s\n", s);
if (scanf_s("%[a-z]s", s, 10)) printf("String2: %s\n", s);
```

Output:

```
abcABC
String1: abc
```

В чём причина такого поведения `scanf_s` и как это исправить? Если не использовать модификатор набора символов, всё работает как надо:

```
char s[11];
if (scanf_s("%s", s, 10)) printf("String1: %s\n", s);
if (scanf_s("%s", s, 10)) printf("String2: %s\n", s);
```

Output:

```
abc
String1: abc
XYZ
String2: XYZ
```

Comment: Что такое `%[a-z]s`? Что это за формат? А именно: что там делает эта `s`?

Comment: Это не формат, а спецификатор формата ввода. В смысле что делает `s`? Указывает формат ввода - строка.

Comment: В `scanf` нет ничего подобного. Формат `%[a-z]` уже сам про себе указывает, что это строка. Никакого `s` в нем нет и никогда не было. Вы прилепили туда это лишнее `s` из-за которого ничего и не работает.

Comment: Вынужден не согласится. Спецификатор набора вводимых символов действительно применим только к модификатору `%s` и поэтому его можно использовать в виде `%[...]`. Написать `%[...]s` и результат будет тот же.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить код `scanf_s("%[a-z]", s, 10); printf("String: %s\n", s);` и `scanf_s("%[a-z]s", s, 10); printf("String: %s\n", s);` - выведет одно и тоже.

Comment: @D .Stark: Не верно. Еще раз никакого `%[]s` в `scanf` не существует. У вас это лишнее `s` просто ни на что не влияет из-за других ошибок, поэтому вы и делаете неправильный вывод о том, что его якобы можно там указывать. Второй `scanf` у вас "выведет одно и то же" потому, как я уже написал в ответе, он завершается с ошибкой и ничего не делает. Он **не переинициализирует** `s`. Вы просто два раза выводите одно и то же `s` из первого `scanf`. Вставьте очистку `s` перед каждым `scanf`, чтобы избавиться от этих заблуждений.

Comment: "У вас это лишнее s просто ни на что не влияет из-за других ошибке" - так нет никаких ошибок. Код, который я привёл в комментарии работает исправно. Я попробовал убрать `s`, но это ничего не изменило.

Comment: Я не так вас понял. Конечно же я использую разные переменные тут: "Попробуйте запустить код `scanf_s("%[a-z]", s, 10); printf("String: %s\n", s);` и `scanf_s("%[a-z]s", s, 10); printf("String: %s\n", s);` - выведет одно и тоже."

Comment: Вызовы не идут один за другим, как в тексте.

Comment: Да такие варианты выведут одно и тоже. Вариант `%[a-z]` успешно прочитает `abc` и успешно завершится. Вариант `%[a-z]s` успешно прочитает `abc` и завершится по ошибке несоответствия формата из-за лишнего `s`. В обоих случаях `scanf` вернет `1`, потому что он возвращает *количество успешно прочитанных аргументов* до первой ошибки (или успешного завершения). Поэтому, как я уже сказал, в таком эксперименте эта лишняя ошибочная `s` просто себя не проявляет.

Comment: Попробуйте `scanf_s("%[a-z]%[A-Z]", s1, 10, s2, 10)`. И отдельно `scanf_s("%[a-z]s%[A-Z]s", s1, 10, s2, 10)`. На вход дайте `abcABC`. Посмотрите, что вернет `scanf` в этих вариантах и что он сможет прочитать.

Comment: Хорошо. В этом вы были правы.

Comment: После этого в эти же два `scanf` дайте на вход `abcsABCs` и снова посмотрите, что они смогут прочитать. Это поможет вам понять, как интерпретируются `scanf` эти лишние `s` в строке формата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Во-первых, форматная строка `"%[a-z]s"` рассматривается `scanf` как спецификатор формата `%[a-z]` за которым следует посторонний самостоятельный символ `s`. Все самостоятельные символы в форматной строке (кроме пробельных) рассматриваются `scanf` как требование того, чтобы такой символ присутствовал во входной строке. В ваших входных строках никакого `s` нет. В результате первый `scanf` завершается досрочно по ошибке несоответствия формата, хоть и после успешного прочтения `abc`. Он возвращает `1`, т.е. первый `printf` срабатывает.

  Что такое `"%[a-z]s"`? Зачем вы поместили туда это `s`? Формат `%[]` является самодостаточным форматом `scanf`. В нем нет и никогда не было никакого `s` после `]`.
- Во-вторых, при входе `abcABC` ваш первый `scanf` читает успешно `abc`, что вы и наблюдаете, а остаток строки - `ABC` - остается во входном буфере. Ваш второй `scanf` ничего не читает, так как вход `ABC` не соответствует формату `%[a-z]`. Если спецификатору формата не удалось ничего прочитать, `scanf` не читает пустую строку, а завершается досрочно по ошибке несоответствия формата. Второй `scanf` возвращает `0`, поэтому ваш второй `if` не срабатывает. Как и должно быть.
- В-третьих, все форматы `scanf`, кроме форматов `%[]` и `%c`, осуществляют изначальное пропускание пробельных символов во входном потоке, перед тем как начать собственно чтение. Если вы введете на вход вашего кода строку `abc` с последующим нажатием <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то во входном буфере образуется последовательность `abc\n`. Первый `scanf` успешно прочитает `abc`, но символ `\n` не совпадает с символом `s`, требуемым первым `scanf`. Поэтому первый `scanf` завершится и оставит символ `\n` во входном потоке. Второй `scanf` начнет чтение именно с этого символа `\n`. Так как символ `\n` не соответствует формату `%[a-z]` второй `scanf` ничего прочитать не сможет и вернет `0`.

Comment: "а ABC остается во входном буфере" - я это понимаю. Писал уже под первым ответом, который автор удалил. Но давайте введём просто "abc", чтобы ничего не осталось в буфере - по прежнему почему то каждый повторный вызов `scanf_s` будет возвращать 0.

Comment: @D .Stark: На какие входные данные вы напускаете ваш "каждый повторный вызов `scanf_s`"?

Comment: Ни на какие. Я запускаю код, который представил в вопросе и получаю то, что получаю, а именно: после того, как выполнится первый `scanf_s` и я введу свои "abc", `printf` выведет их, а второе условие просто не выполнится - повторный вызов `scanf_s` вернёт 0.

Comment: @D .Stark: Как работает код из исходного вопроса я ясно описал в своем ответе (см. "во-вторых"). Как работает код из вашего комментария под вопросом (без `if`) я описал в комментарии под вопросом. Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: "Как работает код из вопроса я ясно описал в своем ответе." - вы ответили лишь, что мне следует убрать `s` и оставить только `[a-z]` в спецификаторе формата, и объяснили, что "ABC" от вводимых "abcABC" остаётся в буфере ввода. Повторю, запустите мой первый пример кода и введите просто "abc" - ситуация не изменится.

Comment: @D .Stark: "Первый пример" - это пример из вопроса? О каком "ситуация не изменится" вы ведете речь? Если ввести просто `abc`, то первый `scanf` прочитает все, т.е. опустошит вход, а второй `scanf` остановится в ожидании дополнительного ввода. При входе "abcABC" второй `scanf` вылетает с ошибкой, а не ждет ввода. То есть все *очень сильно* изменится.

Comment: "Первый пример" - это пример из вопроса?" - да. "первый scanf прочитает все, т.е. опустошит вход, а второй scanf остановится в ожидании дополнительного ввода" - а вот и нет. Второй вызов `scanf_s` просто вернёт 0. Об этой проблеме и речь в вопросе.

Comment: @D .Stark: В вопросе идет речь о входе `abcABC`, как вы сами наставали в комментарии выше. Но смотрите в моем ответе добавленное "в-третьих".

Comment: А т.е. проблема в том, что оставленный в буфере ввода символ переноса не даст повторному вызову `scanf_s` отработать как надо. Ну а если добавить символ переноса в набор сканируемых символов?

Comment: Как можно очистить буфер ввода, чтобы там не оставалось символа переноса после первого вызова `scanf_s`?

Comment: Добавьте в свой ответ [этот код](https://pastebin.com/SwyxUQsQ) и я отмечу его как лучший ответ.

Comment: @D .Stark: Можно добавить символ переноса в набор. Но зачем он вам там? Лучше просто поставьте пробел перед `%[]` во втором `scanf`. В формате `scanf` символ пробела - это приказ пропустить все пробельные символы. То есть формат `" %[a-z]"` будет вести себя в этом отношении так же, как `"%s"`.

Comment: Задача была решить проблему с повторными вызовами `scanf_s`. Решается путём очистки буфера ввода. Добавьте в ответ решение, чтобы другие люди могли его легко найти.

Comment: @D .Stark: Очистка буфера ввода - это совершенно отдельная тема, которая тут уже сотни раз освещалась. Я не хочу плодить еще один ответ об одном и том же, да и еще и под неочевидной темой.